# JQuery text change in h3 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax to call a page which looks like:

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <div class="jqm-block-content invoicehomepage">
        <h3>Invoices</h3>
        <p><a href="pages/" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link">Pages</a></p>
        <p><a href="navigation/" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link">Navigation</a></p>
        <p><a href="loader/" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link">Loader</a></p>
        <p><a href="transitions/" data-ajax="false" class="ui-link">Transitions</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my ajax call is:

```
var pageContent = '';
         $.ajax({
              url: 'jsp/home/home.jsp',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(data) {

                  $.each(data, function(i, v) {
                        $.ajax({
                              url: 'tmpl/homePortlet/'+v.link+'.html',
                              dataType : "html",
                              success: function(html_data) {
                              //var result = $('</div>').append(html_data).find('h3').html();
                                  //$('h3').html(v.portletName);
                                  pageContent +=  html_data;
                                  //console.log(pageContent);
                              }
                        });
                        console.log(pageContent+'sssss');
                  });

              }
        });
```

I want to change text within h3 tag with the value i got from my second ajax call.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the HTML element `h3` by finding it in the content that you have got in your Ajax Call something like this:

```
pageContent = $(html_data).find("h3:first").html(" YOUR-TEXT-YOU-WANNA-PUT ").parent();
```

**Update:**

I think you should use `async: false` in your second ajax call. And secondly, I don't think so that you needs to store/update html into some Variable as you have used `pageContent`. You should use [JQuery .append() method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=append):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'jsp/home/home.jsp',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tmpl/homePortlet/'+v.link+'.html',
                dataType : "html",
                async: false,
                success: function(html_data) {

                    var new_html_data = $(html_data).find("h3:first").html(v.portletName).parent();
                    $('.ui-grid-a').append(pageContent);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right i want to change the text recieve from ajax,  but it does not work for me. html_data show the correct data when i use 'find' it does not returned any value.

Comment: @user2223377 I have implement my example with the HTML you have showed in your question and you can see that its working correctly! Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4oppy38d/)

Comment: but when i used this code at my page it shows object object.

  var pageContent = '';
   $.ajax({
     url: 'jsp/home/home.jsp',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType:'json',
     success:function(data) {
      
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'tmpl/homePortlet/'+v.link+'.html',
         dataType : "html",
         success: function(html_data) {
         var new_html_data = $(html_data).find("h3").html(v.portletName).parent();
         pageContent +=  new_html_data;
         $('.ui-grid-a').html(pageContent);
         }
      });
      });
     
     }
     });

Comment: did you try setting `async: false` property in your second ajax call?

Comment: @user2223377 please check my updates, it may help you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

use:  `$('h3').text(v.portletName);`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your AJAX request is asynchronous..

You can add `async : false,` option in ajax request, so when the request end, second request begin and at success of second ajax request you can change text of H3 tag.

```
var pageContent = '';
$.ajax({
     url: 'jsp/home/home.jsp',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType:'json',
     async:false,// add this line so the success callback execute after response receive.
     success:function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(i, v) {
               $.ajax({
                     url: 'tmpl/homePortlet/'+v.link+'.html',
                     dataType : "html",
                     async:false,// add this line so the success callback execute after response receive.
                     success: function(html_data) {
                         $('h3').html(v.portletName);
                         pageContent +=  html_data;
                     }
               });
               console.log(pageContent+'sssss');
         });

     }
);
```

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: but due to Synchronous call..browser will skip success function

Comment: @user2223377 did you try with async:false ?

Comment: Yes. When i use async:false, in both call page hanged.\

Comment: Can you please make js fiddle